# PHP Script for MYSQL working on one file, not on another

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I currently have an AngularJS application querying a database through a factory linked to a PHP script. The script below works exactly as planned and outputs the JSON used for Angular:

```
<?php
function getCompanyDetails($company_id)
    {
        // Connect to the database.
        require_once("config/connection.php");

        $query = "SELECT id, header, content FROM company_details WHERE company_id = ?;";

        $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

        if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $company_id);
            $stmt->execute();

            $data = $stmt->get_result();

            while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
                $result[] = $row;
            }

            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            $stmt->close();
            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
    }

getCompanyDetails(1);

?>
```

Now, I have other sections of the application which require the exact same action (Selecting results from the database) and I am using the following script (an almost identical copy to the one above):

```
<?php
function getCompanyProjects($company_id)
    {
        // Connect to the database.
        require_once("config/connection.php");

        $query = "SELECT title, description FROM company_projects WHERE company_id = ?;";

        $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

        if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $company_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $data = $stmt->get_result();

            while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
                $result[] = $row;
            }

            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            $stmt->close();
            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
    }

getCompanyProjects(1);

?>
```

The problem is, the second script will not return any results. There are records in the database for the table and I believe I am closing the connection after each use. I have been stuck on this for a while now, does anybody have any idea of what the problem could be?

The query `SELECT title, description FROM company_projects WHERE company_id = ?;` works on phpMyAdmin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think the `;`(semicolon) after the `?` necessary.

Comment: Just removed the `;`, does not seem to have made a difference, yeah.

Comment: Maybe there's an error, do you see anything in the MySQL log? And/or maybe insert a few `if (mysqli_connect_errno())` statements in there to see if you can catch something weird happening?

Comment: I placed a few of the `mysqli_connect_errno()` around the code and all of them returned 0, even the one in the connection configuration script.

Comment: Then try closing your connection after the `echo json_encode`.

Comment: Just tried moving the closing statement to after the encoding bit, still getting no results (the `mysqli_connect_errno()` outputs do appear though.

Comment: If you're certain the query is returning data then maybe dump `$data` and `$row` into the log file, see if anything looks fishy there?

Comment: Just tried dumping the `$data` and `$row` variables, I got this from data:
`object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(2)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(8)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}`

and `$row` returned `NULL`

Comment: And running `SELECT title, description FROM company_projects WHERE company_id = 1;` in console returns results?

Comment: Then there are no records that would match your search criterion.

Comment: Yes, @avip, when I run that query it does return the results with the content inside each row.

Comment: Strange :/the only other thing I can think of is to maybe sub `$row = $data->fetch_assoc()` with `$row = $data->fetch_array();` and dump `$row` to log as before and see if there's any values.

Comment: Btw, you can also print `$data->num_rows` to log to see if your query is behaving as expected. If you get a result of 0, well...something is wrong with the query.

Comment: `$data->num_rows` does display it returned the correct number of rows =/. I'll try the `$data->fetch_array();` bit.

Comment: @avip, doing `echo($result[1][1])` after switching to `fetch_array();` did show the actual content of a row.

Comment: Awesome. If you pass it MYSQLI_ASSOC it should be equivalent to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and if you pass it MYSQLI_NUM it's equivalent to `mysqli_fetch_row()` so...you can play with those to figure out what the issue is. But at least you have data now :)

Comment: @avip, just tried using `fetch_assoc()` again and echoing `$result[1]['title']` and it works properly too. I might just rewrite the code for it to return the data based on this... It still bugs me that the same code does not work twice in a row (the first script runs flawlessly).

Comment: The only thing I'm guessing at is that the first query returns a mix of int and str while the second looks like all string; that might trigger this behaviour in the driver.

Comment: I thought that before as well. I added `id` just to try (increasing one column for the query) and the results are the same, I can manually retrieve one with `$result[1]['title']` but `fetch_assoc();` does not seem to do the trick, @avip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying `fetch_assoc(), fetch_array(), mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and many others, resetting the server a few times, placing `echos` and `var_dumps` everywhere, I realized all the data was being retrieved up until the `while` section.

When I actually iterated `var_dump` inside the while loop, I saw a little symbol for unrecognized character. There was an unescaped quote in one of the last results. After removing this little friend, `fetch_assoc()` started working well again. The problem was in the actual data, not on the code. Both scripts are working properly now with the correct data.

Thanks for all the help, everyone! I had no idea what `var_dump` was before asking this question, a really useful function.